# How can I call a CGI function within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, cgi

How can I call a CGI function within a javascript function? Such like this:

```
function jsFun()  
{  
    //something that can call a CGI function  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

```
function jsFun() {
    $.post(YOUR_CGI_URL, YOUR_PARAMS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this method, how can my cgi function(C function) obtain the params transfered by the js?

Comment: Your C code can read from `stdin`. See [this tutorial](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html#post) for guidelines how to do it.