# script cgi: how to pass a number to the input field into that form?

Tags: forms, variables, cgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post data and retrieve the response using PHP Curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947025/post-data-and-retrieve-the-response-using-php-curl)

It's a tracking from a delivery carrier...

The target url is the following:
[Link](http://dachser.riege.de/cgi-bin/short_shipment_info-dac)

Is it possible to directly pass the number to the page, instead of manually insert the tracking number? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A "low" level solution would be to use a html template library that replaces key words in an .html with values from you cgi application.

take a look at: http://www.algonet.se/~thunberg/template2doc

if that is not what you're looking for check out ajax to query your cgi and return a value - to use in your java script: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Also , look at the jquery library for more elegant solutions:
[How can I call a CGI function within a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826888/how-can-i-call-a-cgi-function-within-a-javascript-function)

Comment: sincerely, reading your guidelines i don't understand how to do that... i haven't to call the cgi function but to pass a number to the field, so directly i can go to destination page instead of being blocked at first page...